# How can I avoid using endless nested replace methods to abbreviate street addresses?

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I am having a hard find figuring out how to write some Visual Basic code that would replace an seemingly endless nested series of `Replace()` methods. Here is what I have right now:

```
Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(rs("street"), "Blvd.", "Boulevard"), "St.", "Street"), "Lane", "Ln."), "Avenue", "Ave."), "Road", "Rd."), "Highway", "Hwy."), "Court", "Ct.")
```

There must be a way to create a function, pass it an address, and more efficiently achieve what I am after.

Comment: I'm confused, Visual Basic or JavaScript?

Comment: @mbojko Looks like VBScript, but it doesn't matter much, since the issue is largely language-agnostic.

Comment: The code above is vbscript. I have a website that includes a file called "subs.asp" In that file I have various subs and functions.

Comment: Please do not move the target when people have already posted answers to the question that was asked initially. If you have a followup question: post a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Statements like that can be broken up into a series of operations by using a temp variable:

```
street = rs("street")
street = Replace(street, "Blvd.", "Boulevard")
street = Replace(street, "St.", "Street")
street = Replace(street, "Lane", "Ln.")
street = Replace(street, "Avenue", "Ave.")
street = Replace(street, "Road", "Rd.")
street = Replace(street, "Highway", "Hwy.")
street = Replace(street, "Court", "Ct.")
```

If you need a more generic approach for arbitrary replacement you could implement a function that takes a value and a dictionary data structure as parameters and then iterates over the dictionary and replaces each key with the corresponding value.

Example implementation in VBScript:

```
streetReplacements = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
streetReplacements.Add "Blvd.", "Boulevard"
streetReplacements.Add "St.", "Street"
streetReplacements.Add "Lane", "Ln."
...

Function CustomReplace(ByVal str, map)
    For Each key In map.Keys
        str = Replace(str, key, map(key))
    Next
    CustomReplace = str
Function

foo = CustomReplace(rs("street"), streetReplacements)
```

Comment: @YvetteColomb There is no "correct" (as in "established") term for what I'm trying to express there. Moreover, the term "Matryoshka commands" might be confused with commands for the [Matryoshka application](https://docs.matryoshkadoll.me/docs/en/server/cli), which I'm most definitely not referring to.

Comment: ah ok! that makes sense. As you will. thanks for the explanation. **mod Note** please stop editing this post and please leave these comments here for a while.